# Binomial coefficients / sums

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I need help solving this task so if anyone had a similar problem it would help me.

$\sum\limits_{k=m}^{n}{n \choose k}{k \choose m}={n \choose m}2^{n-m}$

I tried this:

$\sum\limits_{k=m}^{n}\frac{n!k!}{k!(n-k)!m!(k-m)!}={n \choose m}2^{n-m}\\\sum\limits_{k=m}^{n}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!m!(k-m)!}={n \choose m}2^{n-m}\\\frac{n!}{m!}\sum\limits_{k=m}^{n}\frac{1}{(n-k)!(k-m)!}={n \choose m}2^{n-m}$

Shift $z=k-m\rightarrow k=z+m$

$\frac{n!}{m!}\sum\limits_{z=0}^{n-m}\frac{1}{(n-(z+m))!(z+m-m)!}={n \choose m}2^{n-m}\\\frac{n!}{m!}\sum\limits_{z=0}^{n-m}\frac{1}{(n-z-m)!z!}={n \choose m}2^{n-m}$

And now with this part I don’t know what to do next.
I tried something this way.

$\frac{1}{(n-m)!}+\frac{1}{(n-1-m)!}+...+\frac{1}{n-m}!={n \choose m}2^{n-m}$

But now I don’t know how to calculate the expression on the left side.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: So that you don't have to deal with all of these messy factorials, if you can reason [why $\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{m} = \binom{n}{m}\binom{n-m}{k-m}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534202/prove-binomna-binomn-ab-a-binomnb-binomba/534208#534208) you will have an easier time.

Answer (score 1):

Almost there! $$\frac {n!}{m!} \sum_{z=0}^{n-m} \frac 1{(n-z-m)!z!}=\frac {n!} {(n-m)!m!} \sum_{z=0}^{n-m} \frac {(n-m)!}{(n-m-z)!z!} = \binom n m \sum_{z=0}^{n-m}\binom {n-m}z = \binom n m 2^{n-m}$$

Comment: Thank you ! Can you explain, how you got:$\frac {n!} {(n-m)!m!} \sum_{z=0}^{n-m} \frac {(n-m)!}{(n-m-z)!z!}$

Comment: Multiplying both numerator and denominator by $(n-m)!$.