# Combinatorial proof that $(n-r){n+r-1 \choose r}{n \choose r} = n{n+r-1 \choose 2r}{2r \choose r}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

Combinatorial proof that $(n-r){n+r-1 \choose r}{n \choose r} = n{n+r-1 \choose 2r}{2r \choose r}$.

Typically to combinatorially prove something we need to show that the LHS indeed counts the same thing as the RHS. I am having trouble doing so. One thing I noticed is that on the LHS, we are choosing from a total of $(n-r)+(n+r-1)+(n) = 3n-1$, but on the right we chose from $2n+3r-1$. This is likely no problem at all, but it is still roadblock for me.

Any tips or hints on how to approach this problem are appreciated

Comment: Seems identical to this question. The accepted answer provides a combinatorial proof. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15505/combinatorial-identity-n-r-binomnr-1r-binomnr-n-binomnr-12r?rq=1

Comment: Thank you, I searched for the question before I posted but I didn't see this.